# The entity passed to the `selectId` implementation returned undefined. You should probably provide your own `selectId` implementation

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

[image: The Warning is here]

[image]

https://github.com/rokudo5262/phone this is my project

i want to load the list of brands in smart table but get the warning 

i try to fix but the warning is still there please help 

Brands-features.selector.ts

```
import { createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { State, FeatureKey } from '../reducers';

export const selectBrandsState = createFeatureSelector<State>(FeatureKey);
```

Brands.selector.ts

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { selectBrandsState } from './brands-features.selector';
import { BrandsReducer } from '../reducers';
import { brandAdapter } from '../states/brands.state';

export const selectBrandEntitiesState = createSelector(
  selectBrandsState,
  state => state[BrandsReducer.brandsFeatureKey],
);

export const {
  selectIds: selectBrandIds,
  selectEntities: selectBrandEntities,
  selectAll: selectAllBrands,
  selectTotal: selectTotalBrands,
} = brandAdapter.getSelectors(selectBrandEntitiesState);

export const BrandSelectors = {
  selectBrandEntitiesState,
  selectBrandIds,
  selectBrandEntities,
  selectAllBrands,
  selectTotalBrands,
};
export const selectCurrentBrand = (brand_id) => createSelector(
  selectBrandEntities,
  (brand) => brand[brand_id],
)
```

selector/index.ts

```
export * from './brands-features.selector';
import * as BrandsSelector from './brands.selector';

export {
    BrandsSelector,
};
```

Brand.reducer.ts

```
import { EntityState, EntityAdapter, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { IBrand } from '../../../@core/data/brands';

export interface BrandsState extends EntityState<IBrand> {
    selectedBrandID: number | string | null;
}
export const brandAdapter: EntityAdapter<IBrand> = createEntityAdapter<IBrand>({
    selectId: (brand: IBrand) => brand.brand_id,
    sortComparer: null,
});

export const brandInitialState: BrandsState = brandAdapter.getInitialState({
    selectedBrandID: null,
    entities: {
        0: {},
    },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, turn out the problem is a '''brand_id''' in my `Brand Table`,  `entity.Property(e => e.BrandId).HasColumnName("brand_id");` and `brand_id` in my `Ibrand interface` not in the code.  so i change everything to `brandCode` and the warning is gone.

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Brands>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.BrandCode)

                entity.Property(e => e.BrandCode).HasColumnName("brandCode");

                entity.Property(e => e.BrandName)
                    .HasColumnName("brandName")
                    .HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
                    .HasColumnName("createdBy")
                    .HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedDateTime)
                    .HasColumnName("createdDateTime")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Deleted).HasColumnName("deleted");

                entity.Property(e => e.Remark)
                    .HasColumnName("remark")
                    .HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Status)
                    .HasColumnName("status")
                    .HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedDateTime)
                    .HasColumnName("updatedDateTime")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Updatedby)
                    .HasColumnName("updatedby")
                    .HasMaxLength(255);
            });
```

```
export const brandAdapter: EntityAdapter<IBrand> = createEntityAdapter<IBrand>({
    selectId: (brand: IBrand) => brand.brandCode,
    sortComparer: null,
});
```

```
export interface IBrand {
    brandCode: number;
    brandName: string;
    status: string;
    remark: string;
    deleted: boolean;
    createdBy?: string;
    createdDateTime?: Date;
    lastUpdatedBy?: string;
    lastUpdatedDateTime?: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`createEntityAdapter` has a **selectId** function which expects an `id` field in your element.

Example:

```json
[
    { "id": 1, "name": "Lorem ipsum 1" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Lorem ipsum 2" }
]
```

But, your elements have a custom `id` field like this one:

```json
[
    { "elementId": 1, "name": "Lorem ipsum 1" },
    { "elementId": 2, "name": "Lorem ipsum 2" }
]
```

To solve the issue, i've overwritten the **selectId** method from the `createEntityAdapter` as follows:

```js
const elementAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (e) => e.elementId
});
```

You can find more info here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is in `selectCurrentBrand`, might you share how you use it?

```js
export const selectCurrentBrand = (brand_id) => createSelector(
  selectBrandEntities,
  (brand) => brand[brand_id],
)
```

if you do it like `this.store.select(selectCurrentBrand, 123)`, then the right way is

```js
export const selectCurrentBrand = createSelector(
  selectBrandEntities,
  (brand, brand_id) => brand[brand_id],
)
```

the selector

```js
this.roomgroup$ = this.store.pipe(select(RoomGroupSelectors.selectCurrentRoomGroup, this.id$))
```

Comment: i  used that to call for detail component by id like this<br/>
```export class RoomGroupDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  roomgroup$;
  id$: number;
  constructor(
    private router: ActivatedRoute,
    private store: Store<RoomGroup>
  ) {
    this.id$ = +this.router.snapshot.params.id;
    this.roomgroup$ = this.store.pipe(select(RoomGroupSelectors.selectCurrentRoomGroup(this.id$)));
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(RoomGroupsActions.getRoomGroup({ roomgroups: [] }));
  }```
and i think my problem is relate to selectAlll

Comment: I see, I've updated the answer, you should select it like that: `this.roomgroup$ = this.store.pipe(select(RoomGroupSelectors.selectCurrentRoomGroup, this.id$))`

Comment: i try the ```selectCurrentBrand```  it's normal  and the warning is still there

Comment: then try instead of `brandAdapter.getSelectors(selectBrandEntitiesState)` this one `brandAdapter.getSelectors(selectBrandsState)`. Also might you share how you connect with the StoreModule? Perhaps it can bring light.

Comment: i get the `problem`
```{
"Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<object, State, DefaultProjectorFn<State>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: object) => EntityState<IBrand>'.\n  Type 'State' is missing the following properties from type 'EntityState<IBrand>': ids, entities",
}```

Comment: I see that it's brands -> brands on the screenshot and curious whether it's correct.

Comment: You can check a working example here: https://github.com/satanTime/ngrx-entity-relationship/tree/master/e2e/angular9/src/app/entity/store (check just users) try to compare file by file and it should solve the issue, I think the issue comes from selectors, but it's tough to say which one causes the issue.